# Poetry stuck in infinite install/update

Tags: python, infinite, python-poetry

My issue is that when I execute `poetry install`, `poetry update` or `poetry lock` the process keeps running indefinitely.

I tried using the `-vvv` flag to get output of what's happening and it looks like it gets stuck forever in the first install.

My connection is good and all packages that I tried installing exist.

I use version 1.2.1 but I cannot upgrade to newer versions because the format of the `.lock` file is different and our pipeline fails.

Comment: `poetry cache clear --all pypi` and `poetry cache clear --all _default_cache` did it for me.

Comment: It cloud be related to the parallel installer. Try:

```poetry config experimental.new-installer false```

Comment: OS: Mac 13.3 Python: 3.8
I ran the below two commands and it worked:
`poetry cache clear pypi --all`
`poetry cache clear _default_cache --all`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a clue in an [issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/6471) on the GitHub repo.

If you are using Linux you must delete all `.lock` files in the `.cache/pypoetry` dir in your user home directory.

```bash
find ~/.cache/pypoetry -name '*.lock' -type f -delete
```

If the directory does not exist maybe is in another location.

Then I recommend removing the generated `.lock` file in the project you were doing the installation.

Comment: You can use `poetry config cache-dir` to find the location

Answer (score 10):

Another possibility is a corrupted artifact cache. ([Source](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3352#issuecomment-1369954268))

You can remove all the virtual environments, clear the cache, and delete the contents of the poetry `artifacts` directory using the following:

```
poetry env remove --all
poetry cache clear --all .
rm -rf $(poetry config cache-dir)/artifacts
```

Additionally, you could also delete the `poetry.lock` file and try `poetry install` again.

Comment: less of a nuclear option: just `poetry cache clear --all .` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

if you have boto3 (AWS) as dependency, you should specify the version of urllib3 to be smaller than 2, so for example (in pyproject.toml):

```
boto3 = "^1.24.43"
urllib3 = "<2"
```

This solves the infinite "poetry lock" in my case (nothing else worked).